# How to interface with a bus that's powered when the rest of my circuit is off

Tags: spi, buffer

I'm working on interfacing to a SPI bus that is exhibiting some... bad behavior.

The bus comes from a control box on a toy drumset. The control box is the SPI master, and it can be turned on and off with a built-in button. A separate circuit that reads from the drumpads is the only slave on the bus.

What I am doing is this: I have basically added a master to the bus, in the form of a microcontroller. I know that this isn't a standard use of SPI, but it is for a hobby project, so I don't care. The two masters never operate simultaneously, so there are no conflicts. I mostly enforce this: If the control box is on, I don't plug in the USB cable to the microcontroller (I'm using a Pro Micro). Also, if the microcontroller detects the control box is on, the uC will end SPI communications.

Here is my circuit. I still need to buffer the MISO line, but other than that it's what I'm using.

[image]

There are three states this circuit can be in:

1. Off - control box is off and the Pro Micro is unplugged
2. Control box power - The control box is on, but the Pro Micro is off, thanks to the Schottky diode. The control box is the master, and the Pro Micro is isolated from the circuit.
3. Pro Micro power - The USB cable is plugged in, and the Pro Micro is the master. The control box is off.

My issue occurs during state 1. Although the control box is off, **the SPI lines coming out of it are showing 3.3V**. For some reason, the control box powers MOSI, CLK, and CS even though its VCC shows 0V! When neither the control box nor Pro Micro is on, the buffer is **unpowered**, and the outputs are seeing 3.3V. Somehow this is reverse-powering the buffer, which in turn powers the rest of my circuit.

I'm using a  [SN74AHC125](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc125.pdf) buffer.

Before I started using the buffer, I connected the SPI lines directly to my microcontroller (ATMega 32U4). I had the same problem: The SPI lines powered my Pro Micro through the reverse protection diodes on the pins.

So how can I drive these lines when they are still powered while the rest of my circuit is off?

Comment: Can you attach a diagram of your connections?

Comment: @Bruno Ferreira: Done

Comment: Have you tried to put a 1K resistor between the bus lines and the ground just to to check if the output voltage is active or just a due to pull-ups?

Comment: That's a great idea! Though, it is strange that that would be the case even when the device is off. Once I put the resistors in, how can I check if its active or just due to pull-ups? I don't have an oscilloscope, but I do have a multimeter and logic analyzer

Comment: Check with a multimeter if the 3.3V remains when you power off the circuit.

Comment: Ok, I put a 1K between CS and GND, and measured about 3 volts across the resistor. I'm guessing it's active high :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4018/discussion-between-bruno-ferreira-and-simplecoder)

Comment: This is easy to fix - all that's needed is all the information :-). The words may contain all the available information but words tend to need careful parsing and beating to death and it's easy to write what seems like a full description but have others find it hard to0 follow. whereas [tm] a truly complete circuit diagram can be analysed in its own right. It may need some words in support but the main information needs to be in the diagram. Your diagram is a good start bur=t is, I think, incomplete. sure, my brain tries to add the missed bits, but what may I miss? | ...

Comment: ... I think your supply zener mayu be shown backwards?  | How does the power get to the bus when Vcc is off? How do you turn Vcc off. What is REALLY being turned off. Why can you eg put a switch in the battery leads or cut the leads with a light saber  when not in use:-)). | Back to mack MODFETS in each bus line will turn it off - but simpler should work once we know all facts. ||

Comment: MOSFET switch. Two mosfets. gate to gate, source to source, drains are bidirectional in/out pins. connect gates via 1 megohm say to system V+ to turn on (if N Channel FETS. Ground gates via 1 megohm to turn off. Max voltage switchable is Vgates - Vgs_threshold so need higher than Vbus source and/or very low Vgsth FETS. Works.

Comment: @Russell - I agree, this is a bit confusing at it stands, so we'd just be guessing. A proper circuit diagram, with e.g. information as to exactly *where/how* Vcc is being "switched off" would help to get this answered quickly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: It's actually a Schottky diode, not a Zener. The parts library I used got the symbol wrong and I didn't notice.

Comment: Ok, I've posted the full schematic. However, I think I've found a solution too. I'll write it up now, though I'm still very interested in other opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've solved this. I've added buffers between the control box and the drumpad controller. This is in addition to the buffers between the microcontroller and the drumpad controller.

So, the buffer configuration on (one) of the lines would look like this, with other parts of the circuit omitted for demonstrational purposes.

[image]

The unconnected pins on the buffers are the output enable pins, which I didn't connect (again, demonstrational purposes).

This circuit solves the problem because there is never power on the output of a buffer when the buffer isn't powered. Therefore, no reverse flow occurs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that buffer has input protection diodes. If a voltage is present at the unpowered buffer input, then you will still get current flowing through the protection diodes. It will probably work, but I don't think it's ideal. I'm still puzzled about things like what is being switched off, how many supplies are involved (I think others are too), etc so I may be mistaken. For instance, why can't you just switch the masters (i.e. control box) power off?

Comment: There are two supplies. The control box has two AA batteries, and the Pro Micro is powered through USB. This is a non-standard use of SPI because I'm trying to interface with an already existing device. I can't switch off the power on the control box. When it's on, it's on. My goal with these buffers is for my circuit (the microcontroller) to "stay out of the way" when the control box is on. When the Arduino is powering the slave, however, that's when I take control of it.

Comment: Okay - so what does "off" mean when you say "when the drumset is off, the SPI lines are showing 3.3V" - what is off? Also "...even though Vcc shows 0V!" - which Vcc?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify that. When the control box is off, the SPI lines coming out of the control box are showing 3.3V. The control box's Vcc, however, shows 0V.

Comment: But you just said you couldn't switch the control box off?? Again, what do you mean exactly by "off"? Do you mean standby? Where are you reading the control box Vcc from? Have you opened it up to see where the lines are getting power from? I think if you make all the details really clear, you will probably get some good answers ;-)

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question to hopefully clarify things.